# Не находит файл на локальном сервере

Tags: ajax

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При переносе проекта в отдельную папку, сервер перестал находить один файл. Для запуска локального сервера использую XAMPP, и он перемещен на другой диск.

```
DocumentRoot "G:/Manager"
<Directory "G:/Manager">
```

После переноса проекта в папку SD, весь функционал проекта работает, кроме одного ajax запроса. Он продолжает выдавать ошибку на отсутствие файла по старому пути.

```
GET http://localhost/server/pages/page/handlers/load_images.php?offset=0&tag=name 404 (Not Found)
```

Все файлы уже: *localhost/SD/...*

Часть запроса:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../../server/pages/page/handlers/load_images.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {  
        offset: offset,
        tag: tag
       },
    dataType: 'json'
```

В структуре папок ошибки нет. Возможно я что-то не понимаю в механике работы локального сервера?
Если в путь запроса добавляю название папки, то все работает.

```
url: '../../../SD/server/pages/page/handlers/load_images.php'
```

Comment: Как папки SD и Manager расположены относительно друг друга?

Comment: G:\Manager\SD\...

Comment: Почему вы не хотите прописать относительный url типа `url: '/server/pages/page/handlers/load_images.php'`? Должно решить проблему подобных переносов по папкам

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Сначала я должен выйти из каталога scripts, а потом войти в каталог server

Comment: Если весь проект перенесён в папку SD, а запрос работает при добавлении в путь запроса назавания папки SD, значит вы делаете лишний выход из папки (надо ```url: '../../server/pages/page/handlers/load_images.php'```).

Comment: К сожаление оно так не работает

Answer (score 0):

В смысле не находит файл? Вы пытаетесь сделать запрос **в файл**, а не по **url адресу**!

Для начала вам нужно запустить ваш проект php, что бы у вас **"встал"** сервер. Далее адрес `load_images.php` станет доступ из домена, т.е. примерно по этому `https://localhost/example/path/load_images.php`